# Laravel 6 and vessel error collision with the PHP Redis extension

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am using Laravel vessel to run my Laravel projects. I recently tried running a Laravel project with the new version 6, and I have encountered this error

> LogicException
>
> Please remove or rename the Redis facade alias in your "app" configuration file in order to avoid collision with the PHP Redis extension.

I took a bit to find out how to fix this issue, so I am leaving this question and an answer so other people who find this issue can hopefully fix it without so much struggle.

Answer (score 12):

The problem running the new Laravel version 6 on the docker vessel is that laravel has changed its default driver from `predis` to `phpredis`, this change is creating the error mentioned in the question.

To fix this issue you have to set the driver again to user `predis` instead of `phpredis`.

you can change your `config/database.php` to set `predis` as default

```php
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),
```

or change it in your .env file

```
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

As mention by other users. You could also install `phpredis` if that is an option that works for your project.

Comment: Fixed some mistakes, it's `config/database.php` not `config/app.php`, thanks a lot for this tho

Comment: @Saly3301 you are completely right, my bad. Thanks you for fixing the mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I noticed php_redis extension was missing on system.

With installation of `php_redis` this error went away.

If you are thinking of going back to `predis`, I won't suggest that as predis is abandoned and Laravel is going to remove support for it in future